# face recognition via socket using python and android studio

Tags: python, android

I'm making an app that takes care of recognizing the face and memorizing it. The recognition was made in python while saving the user was made in android studio and the two communicate with each other over the network using sockets.

The idea is to capture a photo via the device's video camera, then this is sent via socket to the python code which recognizes that there is a face in the photo and generates the biometric key. Once the biometric key has been generated, python sends this key to the android studio code where the latter takes this and other user information and inserts it into the room database.

But something is wrong in reality the image between python and android is sent but when I then save the photo from python Output.pgn tells me that the file is corrupted and consequently the biometric key is not generated.

Below I attach a portion, but not all, of the code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import cv2
import math
import numpy as np
import face_recognition
import os
import sys
from socket import *


""" INIT PARAMS """
opencv_file = "/Users/Bia/Desktop/haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml"  # Specifica il percorso del file XML del classificatore OpenCV
zm_fc = 0.50
TCP_IP = "100.101.0.121"   #indirizzo Ip di Temi
T_PORT = 5431

socket_tcp = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
socket_tcp.setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
socket_tcp.bind((TCP_IP, T_PORT))
socket_tcp.listen(1)

def receiveImage(conn):
    try:
        with open('Output.png', 'wb') as img:
            data = conn.recv(2048)
            while data:
                img.write(data)
                data = conn.recv(4096)
        print("Image received from the Temi")
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error during image reception:", str(e))

def sendKey(key, conn):
    try:
        conn.send(key.encode())
        print("Bio key sent to the Temi")
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error sending the bio key:", str(e))
    finally:
        conn.close()

def get_frame():
    try:
        frame = cv2.imread('Output.png')
        if frame is None:
            raise Exception("Failed to read the image")
        
        height, width = frame.shape[:2]
        width = math.floor(width * zm_fc)
        height = math.floor(height * zm_fc)
        dim = (width, height)
        frame = cv2.resize(frame, dim, interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
        return True, frame
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error in get_frame:", str(e))
        return False, None


def start():
    try:
        ret, frame = get_frame()
        if ret and frame is not None:
            face_locations = face_recognition.face_locations(frame)
            face_encodings = face_recognition.face_encodings(frame, face_locations)
            if len(face_encodings) > 0:
                print("Biokey generated " + str(face_encodings[0]))
                return str(face_encodings[0])
    except Exception as e:
        print("Biokey Temi Error:", str(e))
    return None

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("Waiting for the Temi ...")

    while True:
        conn, addr = socket_tcp.accept()

        print("Connection with the Temi done. Ready to receive the image")
        receiveImage(conn)
        print("Generating the biometrical key Temi ....")

        key = start()
        print("The key: " + str(key))

        conn, addr = socket_tcp.accept()
        print("Sending the key back to the Temi ...")
        sendKey(key, conn)

        conn.close()

public class RegisterUserFragment extends Fragment implements
        Robot.NlpListener,
        OnRobotReadyListener,
        Robot.ConversationViewAttachesListener,
        Robot.WakeupWordListener,
        Robot.ActivityStreamPublishListener,
        Robot.TtsListener,
        OnBeWithMeStatusChangedListener,
        OnGoToLocationStatusChangedListener,
        OnLocationsUpdatedListener,
        OnConstraintBeWithStatusChangedListener,
        OnDetectionStateChangedListener,
        Robot.AsrListener   {

    private ImageButton bt_back;
    private NavController navController;
    private FrameLayout parentLayout;
    private GlobalViewModel viewModel;
    private TemiSpeaker temiSpeaker;
    private ImageButton bt_help;
    private Robot robot;
    public static final String ACTION_HOME_WELCOME = "home.welcome", ACTION_HOME_DANCE = "home.dance", ACTION_HOME_SLEEP = "home.sleep";
    public static final String HOME_BASE_LOCATION = "homebase";
    private Button saveActivityBtn;
    private TextInputLayout nameUser, surnameUser;
    private ImageView addImageFace;
    private ArrayList<String> LocationList = new ArrayList<>();
    int CAMERA_PICTURE = 1;
    private Bitmap bitmap;

    /**
     * Setting up all the event listeners
     */
    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        // Add robot event listeners
        robot.addOnRobotReadyListener(this);
        robot.addNlpListener(this);
        robot.addOnBeWithMeStatusChangedListener(this);
        robot.addOnGoToLocationStatusChangedListener(this);
        robot.addWakeupWordListener(this);
        robot.addTtsListener(this);
        robot.addOnLocationsUpdatedListener(this);
        robot.addOnConstraintBeWithStatusChangedListener(this);
        robot.addOnDetectionStateChangedListener(this);
        robot.addAsrListener(this);
    }


    /**
     * Removing the event listeners upon leaving the app.
     */
    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        // Remove robot event listeners
        robot.removeOnRobotReadyListener(this);
        robot.removeNlpListener(this);
        robot.removeOnBeWithMeStatusChangedListener(this);
        robot.removeOnGoToLocationStatusChangedListener(this);
        robot.removeWakeupWordListener(this);
        robot.removeTtsListener(this);
        robot.removeOnLocationsUpdateListener(this);
        robot.removeAsrListener(this);
        robot.stopMovement();
    }

    public RegisterUserFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        viewModel = new ViewModelProvider(getActivity()).get(GlobalViewModel.class);
        temiSpeaker = new TemiSpeaker(viewModel.getTemiRobot());

    }

    /**
     * Designed to close the keyboard when not in use or when you decide not to use it
     */
    public void hideKeyboard(View view) {
        InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(),0);
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        viewModel = new ViewModelProvider(getActivity()).get(GlobalViewModel.class);

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_register_user, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull final View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        navController = Navigation.findNavController(view);

        ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().hide();

        getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);

        robot = Robot.getInstance(); // get an instance of the robot in order to begin using its features.

        parentLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.fragment_registerUserFrameLayout);
        parentLayout.setOnTouchListener((v, motionEvent) -> {
            hideKeyboard(v);
            return true;
        });

        nameUser = view.findViewById(R.id.fragment_insert_activity_text_input_layout);

        surnameUser = view.findViewById(R.id.fragment_insert_activity_text_input_layout_usernameActivity);

        addImageFace = view.findViewById(R.id.addImageFace);
        addImageFace.setOnClickListener(v -> onButtonImageClicked());

        bt_back =  view.findViewById(R.id.btn_back);
        bt_back.setOnClickListener(v -> button_back());

        saveActivityBtn = view.findViewById(R.id.fragment_create_route_button_sava);
        saveActivityBtn.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            saveUserToDatabase();
        });

        bt_help  = view.findViewById(R.id.btn_help);
        bt_help.setOnClickListener(v -> button_help());

    }


    public void onButtonImageClicked() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.CAMERA) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            openCamera();
        } else {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, 100);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if (requestCode == 100) {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                openCamera();
            } else {
                Toasty.error(getActivity(), "You must grant camera permissions to access the camera.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT, true).show();
            }
        }
    }

    private void openCamera() {
        Intent cameraI = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(cameraI, CAMERA_PICTURE);
    }


    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_PICTURE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if (data != null && data.getExtras() != null) {
                Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                if (bitmap != null) {

                    // Controllo delle dimensioni dell'immagine
                    int imageWidth = bitmap.getWidth();
                    int imageHeight = bitmap.getHeight();
                    int imageSizeInBytes = bitmap.getByteCount();

                    // Ora imageSizeInBytes contiene la dimensione dell'immagine in byte
                    // Puoi utilizzare questa informazione per i tuoi scopi, ad esempio, visualizzare la dimensione all'utente o impostare un limite massimo di dimensione per l'immagine.

                    // Verifica se la dimensione dell'immagine supera un limite massimo desiderato (ad esempio, 1 MB)
                    int maxSizeBytes = 1024 * 1024; // 1 MB
                    if (imageSizeInBytes > maxSizeBytes) {
                        // Mostra un messaggio di errore all'utente
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Image size exceeds the maximum allowed limit.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return; // Interrompe l'esecuzione dell'operazione
                    }

                    this.bitmap = bitmap;
                    addImageFace.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    String imagePath = saveImageToFile(bitmap);
                    if (imagePath != null) {

                        new ReceiveBiometricKeyTask().execute(nameUser.getEditText().getText().toString(), surnameUser.getEditText().getText().toString(), imagePath);

                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Failed to save image.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Failed to capture image.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private String saveImageToFile(Bitmap imageBitmap) {
        String imagePath = getActivity().getApplicationContext().getFilesDir().getPath() + "/Output.png";
        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(imagePath);
            imageBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
            fos.close();
            return imagePath;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null; // Restituisci null se c'è stato un errore nel salvataggio dell'immagine
    }


    private void button_back(){
        bt_back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                GlobalViewModel viewModel = new ViewModelProvider(getActivity()).get(GlobalViewModel.class);
                viewModel.initializeForRouteCreation();
                navController.navigate(R.id.action_RegisterUserFragment_to_RegisterOrViewActivityFragment);
            }
        });
    }

    private void button_help() {
        bt_help.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity(),  R.style.AlertDialogStyle);
                builder.setCancelable(true);
                builder.setTitle("Help");
                builder.setMessage(R.string.helperInsertActivityFragment);
                builder.setPositiveButton("I understand", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
                builder.show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onPublish(ActivityStreamPublishMessage message) {
        //After the activity stream finished publishing (photo or otherwise).
        //Do what you want based on the message returned.
        robot.speak(TtsRequest.create("Uploaded.", false));
    }


    @Override
    public void onAsrResult(@NonNull String asrResult) {
        Log.d("onAsrResult", "asrResult = " + asrResult);
    }


    @Override
    public void onConversationAttaches(boolean isAttached) {
        if (isAttached) {
            //Do something as soon as the conversation is displayed.
        }
    }


    /**
     * When adding the Nlp Listener to your project you need to implement this method
     * which will listen for specific intents and allow you to respond accordingly.
     * <p>
     * See AndroidManifest.xml for reference on adding each intent.
     */
    @SuppressLint("Range")
    @Override
    public void onNlpCompleted(NlpResult nlpResult) {
        //do something with nlp result. Base the action specified in the AndroidManifest.xml
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), nlpResult.action, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        switch (nlpResult.action) {
            case ACTION_HOME_WELCOME:
                robot.tiltAngle(23, 5.3F);
                break;

            case ACTION_HOME_DANCE:
                long t = System.currentTimeMillis();
                long end = t + 5000;
                while (System.currentTimeMillis() < end) {
                    robot.skidJoy(0F, 1F);
                }
                break;

            case ACTION_HOME_SLEEP:
                robot.goTo(HOME_BASE_LOCATION);
                break;
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onTtsStatusChanged(TtsRequest ttsRequest) {
        // Do whatever you like upon the status changing. after the robot finishes speaking
    }


    @Override
    public void onWakeupWord(String wakeupWord, int direction) {
        // Do anything on wakeup. Follow, go to location, or even try creating dance moves.
    }


    @Override
    public void onBeWithMeStatusChanged(String status) {
        //  When status changes to "lock" the robot recognizes the user and begin to follow.
        switch (status) {

            case "abort":
                // do something i.e. speak
                robot.speak(TtsRequest.create("Abort", false));
                break;

            case "calculating":
                robot.speak(TtsRequest.create("Calculating", false));
                break;

            case "lock":
                robot.speak(TtsRequest.create("Lock", false));
                break;

            case "search":
                robot.speak(TtsRequest.create("search", false));
                break;

            case "start":
                robot.speak(TtsRequest.create("Start", false));
                break;

            case "track":
                robot.speak(TtsRequest.create("Track", false));
                break;
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onConstraintBeWithStatusChanged(boolean isConstraint) {
        Log.d("onConstraintBeWith", "status = " + isConstraint);
    }


    @Override
    public void onDetectionStateChanged(int state) {
        Log.d("onDetectionStateChanged", "state = " + state);
        if (state == DETECTED) {
            robot.constraintBeWith();
        } else {
            robot.stopMovement();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onGoToLocationStatusChanged(String location, String status, int descriptionId, String description) {
        Log.d("GoToStatusChanged", "descriptionId=" + descriptionId + ", description=" + description);
        switch (status) {
            case "start":
                robot.speak(TtsRequest.create("Starting", false));
                break;

            case "calculating":
                robot.speak(TtsRequest.create("Calculating", false));
                break;

            case "going":
                robot.speak(TtsRequest.create("Going", false));
                break;

            case "complete":
                robot.speak(TtsRequest.create("Completed", false));
                break;

            case "abort":
                robot.speak(TtsRequest.create("Cancelled", false));
                break;
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onLocationsUpdated(List<String> locations) {
        //Saving or deleting a location will update the list.
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Locations updated :\n" + locations, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }


    @Override
    public void onRobotReady(boolean isReady) {
        if (isReady) {
            try {
                final ActivityInfo activityInfo = getActivity().getPackageManager().getActivityInfo(getActivity().getComponentName(), PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
                robot.onStart(activityInfo);
            } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
    }

    private String receivedBiometricKey;

    // Aggiungi questo metodo per memorizzare l'utente nel database dopo aver ricevuto la chiave biometrica
    private void saveUserToDatabase() {
        String name = nameUser.getEditText().getText().toString();
        String surname = surnameUser.getEditText().getText().toString();
        String imagePath = saveImageToFile(bitmap);
        int userId = new Random().nextInt(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

        if (name.isEmpty() || surname.isEmpty() || imagePath == null) {
            robot.speak(TtsRequest.create("Please do not leave any fields empty", true));
        } else {
            // Create a TemiUser instance using the received biometric key
            TemiUser user = new TemiUser(userId, name, surname, imagePath, receivedBiometricKey);

            // Use the AsyncTask to insert the user into the Room database
            new InsertUserDataTask().execute(user);

            robot.speak(TtsRequest.create("I've successfully saved the activity.", false));
            navController.navigate(R.id.action_RegisterUserFragment_to_InsertActivityFragment);
        }
    }

    // AsyncTask to insert user data into Room database
    private class InsertUserDataTask extends AsyncTask<TemiUser, Void, List<TemiUser>> {

        @Override
        protected List<TemiUser> doInBackground(TemiUser... users) {
            TemiUser user = users[0];

            try {
                TemiUserRoomDatabase userDb = Room.databaseBuilder(requireContext(),
                        TemiUserRoomDatabase.class, "TemiUserDatabase.db").build();
                TemiUserDao userDao = userDb.userDao();
                userDao.insertUserIntoDb(user);

                return userDao.getAll();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<TemiUser> userList) {
            if (userList != null) {
                for (TemiUser user : userList) {
                    Log.d("Database", "------------In Room Database ------------");
                    Log.d("Database", "Id User: " + user.getUserId());
                    Log.d("Database", "Name User: " + user.getName());
                    Log.d("Database", "Surname User: " + user.getSurname());
                    Log.d("Database", "Image Path: " + user.getImagePath());
                    Log.d("Database", "Biometric Key: " + user.getBiometricKey());
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // AsyncTask to receive the biometric key from the Python server
    private class ReceiveBiometricKeyTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        private static final String SERVER_IP = "your_server_ip"; // Replace with your server IP
        private static final int SERVER_PORT = 5434;
        private static final int TIMEOUT_IN_MILLISECONDS = 5000;

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            String name = params[0];
            String surname = params[1];
            String imagePath = params[2];

            try {
                Socket pythonSocket = new Socket();
                pythonSocket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(SERVER_IP, SERVER_PORT), TIMEOUT_IN_MILLISECONDS);

                OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(pythonSocket.getOutputStream());
                out.write("scatta_foto\n");
                out.flush();

                File photoFile = new File(imagePath);
                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(photoFile);
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                OutputStream os = pythonSocket.getOutputStream();
                int bytesRead;
                while ((bytesRead = fis.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    os.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                }
                os.flush();
                fis.close();

                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pythonSocket.getInputStream()));
                String biometricKey = in.readLine();
                in.close();

                pythonSocket.close();

                return biometricKey;
            } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return "Error: Connection timeout. Please try again.";
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return "Error: Unable to connect to the server. Please check the server settings.";
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String biometricKey) {
            if (biometricKey != null && !biometricKey.startsWith("Error")) {
                receivedBiometricKey = biometricKey;

                // Proceed to save the user in the database
                saveUserToDatabase();

            } else {
                String errorMsg = (biometricKey != null) ? biometricKey : "Error receiving biometric key. Please try again.";
                robot.speak(TtsRequest.create(errorMsg, false));
            }
        }
    }
}
```